# Собранный из исходников clang под mac os не видит ld

Tags: c++, macos, clang, ld

Собрал последнюю версию clang под mac os. При попытке скомпилировать код, clang выдает ошибку что не видит компоновщик ld. Но ld установлен по дефолтному пути /usr/bin/ld, в PATH есть этот путь, как мне явно указать clang где лежит компановщик?

```
CMake Error at /Users/a.mamedov/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/212.5712.21/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/local/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/a.mamedov/dev/cxxcoro/cmake-build-debug-clang16/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_faa40/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_faa40.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_faa40.dir/build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_faa40.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/local/bin/clang    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_faa40.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_faa40.dir/testCCompiler.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_faa40.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/a.mamedov/dev/cxxcoro/cmake-build-debug-clang16/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_faa40
    "/Users/a.mamedov/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/212.5712.21/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_faa40.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/local/bin/clang -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/cmTC_faa40.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_faa40 
    clang-16: error: unable to execute command: Executable "ld" doesn't exist!
    clang-16: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_faa40] Error 1
    make: *** [cmTC_faa40/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: Надо было еще собрать lld и сделать собственный тулчейн для cmake

Comment: @user7860670,  lld тоже собрал, как сделать тулчейн